# Bash convert file to lowercase and sort

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, lowercase, ifs

I am trying to write a script that will take in an `inputFile`, convert it to lowercase, sort it, and then store the results back in the original file. I'm fairly new to bash, so this is the solution I've come up with so far:

```
awk '{ print tolower($0) }' $inputFile

index=0
for i in `cat $inputFile`
do                   
    tables[${index}]=$i
    index=$(($index + 1))
done

IFS=$'\n' tables=($(sort <<<"${tables[*]}"))
rm -r $inputFile
printf "%s\n" "${tables[@]}" >> $inputFile
```

The sorting aspect of this works fairly well, but I am unable to store the results of `awk` to the original `inputFile`, so the sorted table still includes uppercase letters. I have tried to redirect the output of `awk` to `> inputFile`, but this didn't work either.

Sample `inputFile`:

```
TABLE.thisisaTABLE
taBLe.hellO
HELLO.table
hi.table
```

Desired output (back into original `inputFile`):

```
hello.table
hi.table
table.hello
table.thisisatable
```

Comment: it looks interesting and there are few things to be improved (`while read line; do ... done < file` is preferred over `for i in cat...`). Could you indicate a sample input file with the desired output?

Comment: That usage of `IFS` is **not** local to that one line.

Comment: @fedorqui I've updated the OP to include the info.

Comment: What version of bash are you targetting?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm fairly unfamiliar with `IFS` so you might have to explain what I'm doing wrong there. I'm using bash `4.1.2`

Comment: Why not just `awk '{ print tolower($0) }' $inputFile | sort -o $inputFile`?  Is there other processing your're expecting to do while sorting?

Comment: A line like `FOO=bar some_command` normally assigns `FOO` a value *only* for that command. `IFS` doesn't work that way though. So that assignment to `IFS` remains in effect for the rest of your script.

Comment: Does `awk '{map[tolower($0)]++} END {for (line in map) {print line}}' $inputFile | sort` do what you want?

Comment: @n0741337 simply because I didn't know any better. This works great! Please submit it as an answer so that I can accept.

@EtanReisner thanks for the tip about `IFS`. I'll be cautious about its use in the future.

Comment: @EtanReisner Your statement about `IFS` is wrong: `IFS=test ls; declare -p IFS`.

Comment: echo "Poor old tr. How quickly you are Forgotten." | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Try the OP's example. `IFS=test foo=bar; declare -p IFS`. So apparently it is more nuanced then I had previously thought. I would have sworn that IFS behaved badly in many cases but the cases seem to be much more limited then I believed. The OP's happens to be among them though. But thanks for the correction.

Comment: @EtanReisner It's just a regular assignment: try `a=b c=d e=f g=h` and observe that assignments don't need to be separate statements. In OP's case, it's just what happens. `IFS` isn't special at all.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Indeed (I still feel like there was something else with `IFS` but have no proof at the moment). Anyway, it just so happens that most assignments don't have the same side-effects as `IFS` so don't cause the same problems. Ultimately, my comment should probably have just been "You are setting IFS for the whole rest of the script on that line. You probably don't want to do that".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-o` flag of sort to perform both the sort and the redirection back into the original file:

```
awk '{ print tolower($0) }' $inputFile | sort -o $inputFile
```

Comment: I could be wrong but that does not look safe to me and I wouldn't put money on `$inputfile` not being overwritten before `sort` is finished. Yes, `sort -o` lets you specify the same name as an input file and guarantees it's safety but that is not what you're doing with that script so `sort` may think it's OK to init the output file before it's finished reading all it's input.

Comment: @EdMorton - Good point; probably depends on the sort implementation.  For example, this [GNU sort manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) says its safe unless you're using the `--merge(-m)` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution with **sed**:

```
sed 's/.*/\L&/' $inputFile | sort -o $inputFile
```

**Explanation**: `s/.*/\L&/` means convert entire line (`.*`) to lower case using `\L`. `&` stands for the matched pattern.

Comment: or, if you want to pipe via STDIN, `echo HELLO | sed -e 's/.*/\L&/'` ==> `hello`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'push @a, lc; END { print join("\n", sort @a) }' $inputFile
hello.table
hi.table
table.hello
table.thisisatable
```

Works by:

```
perl -lne      # invoke perl with a loop around the lines of the file
push @a, lc;   # make line read lower case; push the result
END            # block of code executed at the end
{ print join("\n", sort @a) }   # Print each sorted line with \n
```

If you want to modify the file in place:

```
$ perl -i.bak -0777 -lne 'print join("\n", sort map(lc, split /\n/))' file.txt
```

And if you don't want a backup file made:

```
$ perl -i -0777 -lne 'print join("\n", sort map(lc, split /\n/))' file.txt
```